# Pandas series rename axis failure

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating Pandas MulitiIndex series from a dict. It succeeds normally but rename_axis fails when dict is empty

`series = pd.Series({('a','b','c'):1,('a','d','e'):2}, dtype='float64').rename_axis(['first_column','second_column','third_column'])`

`series`

```
first_column  second_column  third_column
a             b              c               1.0
              d              e               2.0
dtype: float64
```

This fails when the dictionary is empty

`series = pd.Series({}, dtype='float64').rename_axis(['first_column','second_column','third_column'])`

```
   1237             raise ValueError("Names must be a list-like")
   1238         if len(values) != 1:
-> 1239             raise ValueError(f"Length of new names must be 1, got {len(values)}")
   1240 
   1241         # GH 20527

ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 3
```

I could check if the dictionary is empty and create series differently

```
series = pd.Series({}, dtype='float64', index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([], names=['first_column', 'second_column', 'third_column']))
```

Wondering if there is better way to create series avoiding the explicit if condition for empty dict.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason to create the empty Series? If not you can do something like `if d:` to only create the Series when the dict `d` is not empty. Since you already expect the dicts to be conceptually different, is there any reason to expect the tuples to always have 3 elements?

Comment: Empty Series is needed as it is used for further processing. Tuples will always have 3 elements